# How to force Postgresql "cartesian product" behavior when unnest'ing multiple arrays in select?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Postgresql behaves strangely when unnesting multiple arrays in the select list:

```
select unnest('{1,2}'::int[]), unnest('{3,4}'::int[]);
 unnest | unnest
--------+--------
      1 |      3
      2 |      4
```

vs when arrays are of different lengths:

```
select unnest('{1,2}'::int[]), unnest('{3,4,5}'::int[]);
 unnest | unnest
--------+--------
      1 |      3
      2 |      4
      1 |      5
      2 |      3
      1 |      4
      2 |      5
```

Is there any way to force the latter behaviour without moving stuff to the from clause?

The SQL is generated by a mapping layer and it will be very much easier for me to implement the new feature I am adding if I can keep everything in the select.

Comment: Note that the behavior of the second query has changed in Postgres 10: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=044f812b41b1c9a18b3367dea92f7370  the general advice is to not use multiple set returning functions in the select list.

Comment: Drat. If it doesn't work in Postgres 10 then my approach is doomed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/release-10.html

> Set-returning functions are now evaluated before evaluation of scalar
>   expressions in the SELECT list, much as though they had been placed in
>   a LATERAL FROM-clause item. This allows saner semantics for cases
>   where multiple set-returning functions are present. **If they return
>   different numbers of rows, the shorter results are extended to match
>   the longest result by adding nulls. Previously the results were cycled
>   until they all terminated at the same time, producing a number of rows
>   equal to the least common multiple of the functions' periods**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So you can't do what I want in the select. I had to go with ```select a, b from unnest('{1,2}'::int[]) as a, unnest('{3,4}'::int[]) as b```

Comment: @DavidTinker That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with version 12.12 of Postgres and as mentioned by OP in a comment, having two `unnest()` works as expected when you move those to the `FROM` clause like so:

```
SELECT a, b
  FROM unnest('{1,2}'::int[]) AS a,
       unnest('{3,4}'::int[]) AS b;
```

Then you get the expected table:

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 3
2 | 4
```

As we can see, in this case the arrays have the same size.

In my case, the arrays come from a table. You can first name the name and then name column inside the `unnest()` calls like so:

```
SELECT a, b
  FROM my_table,
       unnest(col1) AS a,
       unnest(col2) AS b;
```

You can, of course, select other columns as required. This is a normal cartesian product.